# OpenPyXl: Mark row as heading

Tags: python, openpyxl

This snippet works fine:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

data = [
    ['Year', 'Amount'],
    ['2016', '1000'],
    ['2017', '1300'],
    ['2018', '1500'],
]

wb = Workbook()
for row in data:
    wb.active.append(row)

wb.save('test.xlsx')
```

Now I would like to make the first row (Year, Amount) a heading.

How to do this with [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)?

Comment: Do you mean you want to freeze first row?

Comment: What do you mean by heading?

Comment: @CharlieClark with heading I mean the things you usually do in Excel to distinguish between data and heading. But to be honest: I never use Excel. I can't tell you in detail how to do this in Excel.

Comment: @guettli please you can change the font color, freeze first row and make print_title_rows. Please check the answer if may  solve your problem. :)

Comment: So just set the font to bold for the cells. Or create a table. Headings mean different things to different people and, apart from tables, there is no defition in OOXML of what they are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can mark first row as Header by **changing font color,** **freezing First row** and making first row as **print_title_rows**

Adding aRGB hex values color to font

> font = Font(color="FF0000")
>
> ws["A1"].font = font
>   ws["B1"].font = font

[link for style](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/styles.html)

If your trying to **Freeze Top Row** ie first row and add Add **Print Titles** to first row.
You can achieve this by using setting **freeze_panes** and **print_title_rows** of worsheet properties.

> ws.freeze_panes = "A2"
>
> ws.print_title_rows='1:1'

freeze_panes will freeze rows above the given cell and must be call after some data has been inserted.

[links for worksheet modules](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html?highlight=freeze#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.freeze_panes)

[print settings](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/print_settings.html)

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Font
data = [
    ['Year', 'Amount'],
    ['2016', '1000'],
    ['2017', '1300'],
    ['2018', '1500'],
]

wb = Workbook()
for row in data:
    wb.active.append(row)
font = Font(color="FF0000")
ws = wb.active
ws.freeze_panes = "A2"
ws["A1"].font = font
ws["B1"].font = font
ws.print_title_rows = '1:1'
wb.save('test.xlsx')
```

Answer (score -1):

just use pandas to deal with it,(but looks difficult),you can also see the example in
https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pandas.html

```
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

for r in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=True, header=True):
    ws.append(r)
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

for r in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=True, header=True):
    ws.append(r)

for cell in ws['A'] + ws[1]:
    cell.style = 'Pandas'

wb.save("pandas_openpyxl.xlsx")
```

Comment: In this example, you really only need to set the style for the relevant cells, pandas itself is irrelevant.