# Python: Read excel file with formulas and header as a pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

is it possible to read/import formulas of excel sheet using pd.read_excel?
If yes, How?
If No, then is there any package which can do that along with keeping row 3 of excel file as header?

Comment: OpenPyXL p package can, you should check this out [How can I see the formulas of an excel spreadsheet in pandas / python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42102674/how-can-i-see-the-formulas-of-an-excel-spreadsheet-in-pandas-python)

Comment: Thanks John Taylor, I have been successful in reading the formulas with openpyxl but still finding a way to assign one of the row as header.
Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: you can also check this thread might be better (OpenPyXl: Mark row as heading)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55041209/openpyxl-mark-row-as-heading]

Comment: it has two methods one using pandas and another using Freeze in OpenPyXL